# Paste multiple files from clipboard not working

Tags: javascript

So i noticed everytime i paste some file, if i have more than 1 file on my clipboard area it only pastes 1 file, the others my code just don't process.

Here is the snippet to reproduce, even if i have more than 1 file on clipboard it only inserts 1 item in the array. I'm trying to figure out what is happening. (use image files to test).

```js
const inputFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
})

const getBase64Files = async (items) => {
  const base64Files = []  
  
  for (const item of items) {  
     const base64 = await inputFileToBase64(item.getAsFile())
     
     base64Files.push(base64)
  }
  
  return base64Files
}

document.addEventListener('paste', async (event) => { 
  console.log('pasted')
  const items = event.clipboardData.items
  const files = await getBase64Files(items)
  console.log(files)
})
```

```html
PASTE HERE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataTransferItemList` `items` seems to be consumed as soon as the event loop allows it to; it doesn't wait for a `FileReader` to read it. So, by the time the first file is read, `items` is empty.

If you allow the task queue to do its stuff, even with a `setTimeout` of 0, you lose all files:

```js
  const items = event.clipboardData.items
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0)) //wait 0ms
  const files = await getBase64Files(items) //no items, no files
```

and that's also happening with the working version of `getBase64Files` below.

Regardless of the explanation (which one might improve upon), it is always a good idea to start all reading at the same time and await for all to complete:

```js
const getBase64Files = async (items) => {
  const base64Files = []

  await Promise.allSettled(
    Array.from(items).map(
      item => inputFileToBase64(item.getAsFile()).then(
        file => base64Files.push(file)
      )
    )
  )
   
  return base64Files
}
```

and that works.

Comment: It's an interesting problem - your code seems fine but it doesn't work... Of course, this is just an example/prototype and I'm sure you'll probably explore other ways to achieve your goal as this still seems fragile even with my patch.

Answer (score 1):

This is not your mistake. For some reason, the item list only contains 1 item in chrome. In Firefox, it seems to be 0. No matter how many files you copy.

You should probably use the Clipboard API instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Comment: But if i try to `console.log(event.clipboardData.items)` it returns me the right length of items

Comment: Really? Thats weird. I tried it and it returned length = 1 when I pasted multiple files. But it seems to only iterate through 1 item. But as I already said, using the Clipboard API is the better approach.

Comment: It returns me `DataTransferItemList { 0: DataTransferItem, 1: DataTransferItem, length: 2 }` in both Chrome and Firefox, but the issue is when i try to iterates over it.